# WOPI Token - Secret Key

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, secret-key, ms-wopi

I'm trying to implement WOPI on my application but im having a hard time to find the **secret key** to generate a token see below image for the sample code from github

Generate Token code:

```
public SecurityToken GenerateAccessToken(string userId, string resourceId)
    {
        var user = _userDatabase[userId];

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = user.Identities.FirstOrDefault(),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1), //access token ttl: https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/concepts.html#term-access-token-ttl
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(Key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        };

        return _tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    }
```

Get **Key**, the sample below is just a dummy key but there's no guide where to get it

```
private SymmetricSecurityKey Key
    {
        get
        {
            if (_key is null)
            {
                //RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
                //byte[] key = new byte[128];
                //rng.GetBytes(key);
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("secretKeysecretKeysecretKey123"/* + new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond).Next(1,999)*/);
                _key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
            }

            return _key;
        }
    }
```

Im using this GitHub below for the reference
https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/blob/5a1c78a9102d56b62e8023c2c045d6f056008ed2/WopiHost.FileSystemProvider/WopiSecurityHandler.cs#L66

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the key validation is intentionally left up to the developer here. You can use the preconfigured `SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256` or you can [swap](https://geeksqa.com/swapping-symmetricsecuritykey-for-asymmetricsecuritykey-for-jwt) it with an asymmetric algorithm.

If you wish to continue using the symmetric key, the idea is to configure the environment with the key. So you can put your secret key in the environment variables and replace `secretKeysecretKeysecretKey123` with `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WOPI_SECRET")`.

However, this part of the OS project is not quite finalized so it may require a little more work here and there.